# New to Ubuntu/Linux - Which distro should I install?

Tags: desktop-environments, versions, distro-recommendation

I'm switching over from Windows 7 to Ubuntu (basically because I want to try something new). I'm a basic user; I really only use my PC for iTunes, Web Browsing, some Steam gaming, and multimedia sharing to my Samsung TV. I'm very organized and want the best looking and fluent system. What should I install? Just the regular Ubuntu or maybe MATE? I don't know the differences in any of these.... please help!

Comment: Your question is a matter of opinion so not a good fit for AskUbuntu. Feel free to try them all and make a choice on what -you- like. Canonical (owns Ubuntu) does not restrict you in any way in *using* Ubuntu.

Comment: Not only an opinion based question, but regarding of iTunes and streaming to your Samsung tv, you'll have to ask the specific companies that develop those software to support Linux. Good luck with that.

Comment: I'd say set up dual boot.  Have both windows and Ubuntu.  Now depending on your computer,  how much ram or graphics it has , you might go either with Ubuntu or Lubuntu. Lubuntu and X Ubuntu have plus in more familiar interface to a windows user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) or [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com). Before an year, I was a Windows user and tried several versions of Linux. I found Linux Mint as the easiest one, since it comes with most of the codecs and applications by default. Also it's user interface is easy to learn for Windows users. Once you fall in love with Linux (It may take some time, but definitely you will) you can try other distributions and go with your preferred one. (My current OS is Ubuntu 14.04, because of my personal taste.)

A friendly advice dear, don't start with a Linux version which is designed for some special purposes like for hacking or lightweight for old hardware.

Comment: Note that AskUbuntu doesn't support Linux Mint. So if that's important, the OP would do better to stick with Ubuntu/Ubuntu MATE.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. Could you please suggest me, what to do? Should I remove this answer?

Comment: No, as far as I'm concerned your answer is fine. You could always include a sentence on the end to the effect that he won't be able to ask Linux Mint questions on Ask Ubuntu, and that there is Unix & Linux on Stack Exchange, as well as the Mint forums.

Answer (score 0):

They are both good choices and both fully functional. Ubuntu MATE is arguably lighter for older hardware but beyond that your question is too subjective to answer. It's a matter of taste.

My recommendation is to try them both out in live environments so you can see with  a minimum of fuss which you prefer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I beg to differ. My answer is constructive and answers the OP's question fully to the extent it can be answered. Saying his question is subjective is not critiquing it. It is pointing out the limitations of my response.

Comment: That is just the standard response from the review que, the specific reason I flagged this was, you answered the question with a question and a question is not an answer `Why not try them both out live and see which one you prefer?`, leave a comment saying why you disagree but it is out of my hands now it has gone to the mods.

Comment: That's a suggestion not a question. I will remove the question mark so the OP doesn't get confused.